# Установка nuget-пакетов оффлайн

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Я использую MVC5-фреймворк для разработки приложения. При выборе режима аутентификации "Individual user accounts", в проект устанавливается ряд nuget-пакетов (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.* и т.п.). Разработка ведется на машине, не подключенной к интернету. IDE - Visual Studio 2015.

- Есть ли возможность добавить эти пакеты в локальный репозиторий? (У
  меня на компьютере есть папка, на которую ссылается NPM, в ней
  хранятся некоторые *.nupkg-файлы).
- Как мне получить и загрузить в эту папку локально пакет **со всеми его зависимостями в *.nupkg-формате**, чтобы не скачивать каждый файл-зависимость по отдельности?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмите packages.config от своего проекта, перенесите его на машину, на которой есть интернет. Положите рядом [nuget.exe](http://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe) и запустите восстановление пакетов:

```
nuget restore -PackagesDirectory packages
```

После этого скопируйте nupkg-файлы на машину без интернета, в свою локальную папку-репозиторий.

Answer (score 0):

> Разработка ведется на машине, не подключенной к интернету.

На другом компьютере, подключенном к интернет, надо скачать `https://www.nuget.org/nuget.exe` и запустить с параметрами `install имя_пакета`.
Полученные пакеты можно скопировать на компьютер с Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Я делал так.

1. Собираем все пакеты в одну папку.
2. В настройках `MSVS Сервис → Параметры → Диспетчер пакетов NuGet → Источники пакетов` удалите все онлайн источники и задайте свои указав локальную папку с нужным пакетом.
3. В меню `Сервис → Диспетчер пакетов NuGet → Управление пакетами NuGet для решения` выбрать `Источник пакета → Все`. Все пакеты будут доступны оффлайн. Минус каждый пакет нужно добавлять как источник.
   Или через консоль используя команду
   Install-Package "C:\Path\To\Some\File.nupkg"
   Обратите внимание путь в кавычках, иначе будет ошибка, если в пути есть пробелы.