# Не могу установить Nuget пакет Mahapps.Metro в Visual studio 2015 Enterprise

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, metro-framework

Здравствуйте проблема заключается в следующем понадобился пакет для создания Metro приложений, пытаюсь выгрузить его с nuget следующим образов

1. Создаю проект Wpf в студии
2. Открываю контекстное references и Manage nugets ищу паке, нашел нажимаю установить, минут 5 думает и вываливается ошибки

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package
>   'MahApps.Metro.1.4.3' with respect to project 'Metro', targeting
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0' Attempting to resolve dependencies for
>   package 'MahApps.Metro.1.4.3' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
>   Resolving actions to install package 'MahApps.Metro.1.4.3' Resolved
>   actions to install package 'MahApps.Metro.1.4.3'
>   System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception.
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.    at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.Net.Http.DelegatingStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count)    at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Char[]
>   userBuffer, Int32 userOffset, Int32 desiredChars, Boolean&
>   readToUserBuffer)    at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer,
>   Int32 index, Int32 count)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadData(Boolean append, Int32
>   charsRequired)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer(Char quote)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseString(Char quote)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadContentFrom(JsonReader r)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadTokenFrom(JsonReader reader)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader)    at
>   NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.d__27.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.DependencyInfo.Utils.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.RegistrationResourceV3.d__10.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.RegistrationResourceV3.d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   NuGet.Protocol.PackageMetadataResourceV3.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.d__13.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.d__6.MoveNext()
>   ========== Finished ==========

Ошибку понял, что нет подключения к сайту, но из браузера заходил и все работает, правда недавно появилось проблемка на сайты https долго заходит (иногда неудачно) с чем связано не знаю, сегодня запустил установку обновлений установил все критичные обновления но все также. в чем причина кто подскажет, можно ли как то вручную установить этот пакет, например скачать в локальный git (а оттуда в проект)

[Установка nuget-пакетов оффлайн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476805/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-nuget-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD) скачал nuget offline

Запустил устанавливается выбрасывается ошибка

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] (c) Корпорация Майкрософт
>   (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.
>   C:\Users\user.user-pc>C:\Users\user.user-pc\Downloads\Programs\nuget.exe
>   install  mahapps.metro Feeds used:
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json   C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\NuGetPackages\
>
> GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/index.json
>   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/index.json
>   1193ms   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.1.0/0.9.9.4
>   7-alpha.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.9.9.48-alph
>   a/0.11.0.31-alpha.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.11.0.32-alp
>   ha/0.11.2.14-alpha.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.11.2.15-alp
>   ha/0.13.0.58-alpha.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.13.0.59-alp
>   ha/0.13.0.124-alpha.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.13.0.125-al
>   pha/0.14.0-alpha68.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.14.0-alpha6
>   9/0.15.0-alpha2.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.15.0-alpha2
>   0/0.15.0-alpha79.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.15.0-alpha8
>   /1.0.1-alpha027.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.0.1-alpha02
>   8/1.1.2-alpha001.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.1.2-alpha00
>   2/1.1.3-alpha071.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.1.3-alpha07
>   2/1.1.3-alpha142.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.1.3-alpha14
>   3/1.1.3-alpha210.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.1.3-alpha21
>   1/1.3.0-alpha012.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.3.0-alpha01
>   5/1.3.0-alpha080.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.3.0-alpha08
>   1/1.3.0-alpha155.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.3.0-alpha15
>   7/1.4.0-alpha036.json   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.4.0-alpha03
>   7/1.4.3.json   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.1.0/0.9.9.47
>   -alpha.json 951ms   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.1.2-alpha002
>   /1.1.3-alpha071.json 1236ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.15.0-alpha20
>   /0.15.0-alpha79.json 1276ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.1.3-alpha143
>   /1.1.3-alpha210.json 1380ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.3.0-alpha157
>   /1.4.0-alpha036.json 1386ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.14.0-alpha69
>   /0.15.0-alpha2.json 1444ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.11.0.32-alph
>   a/0.11.2.14-alpha.json 1961ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.9.9.48-alpha
>   /0.11.0.31-alpha.json 2493ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.13.0.59-alph
>   a/0.13.0.124-alpha.json 3019ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.11.2.15-alph
>   a/0.13.0.58-alpha.json 3553ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.15.0-alpha8/
>   1.0.1-alpha027.json 4068ms   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.1.3-alpha072
>   /1.1.3-alpha142.json 4587ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.0.1-alpha028
>   /1.1.2-alpha001.json 5128ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/0.13.0.125-alp
>   ha/0.14.0-alpha68.json 5674ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.3.0-alpha081
>   /1.3.0-alpha155.json 6166ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.3.0-alpha015
>   /1.3.0-alpha080.json 6700ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.4.0-alpha037
>   /1.4.3.json 7219ms   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/1.1.3-alpha211
>   /1.3.0-alpha012.json 7763ms An error occurred while retrieving package
>   metadata for 'mahapps.metro' from sou rce 'nuget.org'.   The download
>   of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/mahapps.metro/page/
>   0.1.0/0.9.9.47-alpha.json' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.   Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
>
> C:\Users\user.user-pc>

Comment: Скачал nuget ofline

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Ваш проект работает на версии .NET ниже, чем может поддерживать сам Mahapps. + возможно папка, в которую должен ложится сам mahapps защищена от записи.
Это тому сведетельство:

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package
>   'MahApps.Metro.1.4.3' with respect to project 'Metro', targeting
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0' Attempting to resolve dependencies for
>   package 'MahApps.Metro.1.4.3' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
>   Resolving actions to install package 'MahApps.Metro.1.4.3' Resolved
>   actions to install package 'MahApps.Metro.1.4.3'